# How to get SQL command generated by Generate function in EF-Core MigrationSqlGenerator?

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

Using EF-Core to handle custom SQL command over migration. Is it possible to get the SQL command generated by an overrided `Generate` function?

```
protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
{
      base.Generate(operation, model, builder);
      var generatedSQL = ?; // <-- how can I get this SQL command?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MigrationSqlGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationssqlgenerator?view=efcore-5.0) produces a list of [`MigrationCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationcommand?view=efcore-5.0) instances which can be obtained from the [`MigrationCommandListBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationcommandlistbuilder?view=efcore-5.0) via [`GetCommandList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationcommandlistbuilder.getcommandlist?view=efcore-5.0) method. The SQL command text is contained in the [`CommandText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationcommand.commandtext?view=efcore-5.0) property of the `MigrationCommand`.

So if you are sure that the base call generates a single command, then you could take the last command from that list afterwards:

```cs
var generatedSQL = builder.GetCommandList().Last().CommandText;
```

A more generic approach without any assumptions could be like this:

```cs
var commands = builder.GetCommandList();
var start = commands.Count;
base.Generate(operation, model, builder);
for (int i = start; i < commands.Count; i++)
{
    var generatedSQL = commands[i].CommandText;
}
```